# Analytic solution of Laplace equation for electric potential inside and outside an interface

Tags: differential-equations

This post is about the Mathematica implementation of a code to get directly the analytic solution of Laplace equation for the electric potential in cylindrical coordinates.

I was reading an article ([Reddy, M. N. 2009](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301932209001116)) and I wanted to try out the calculations by myself. Started on a sheet of paper and eventually arrived at the solution by separation of variables. I attach the photo with the statement of the problem and the solution.

Disclaimer: I was recommended to try learn Mathematica a few weeks ago, so I am quite new to it and to the forum.

However, I got a little curious and decided to try to do these calculations with Mathematica.
I meant to write specifically the code for this problem, but I guess it is too advanced for my current knowledge (I have just learned the basics): for example, I still have to understand if Mathematica is able to solve the Laplace equation analytically.

[image]

Is there anyone that knows if it is possible and if yes, how to code this to get the solution?
I think that would be really helpful for me: I have to admit that, when it comes to coding it is not exactly my thing and I truly learn if I start from some correct lines.

Moreover, could someone recommend a good manual to learn coding in Mathematica in an organic way? My self-studying is not being that effective.

Comment: From your diagram, you are using polar coordinates as you have no $z$. But you say you want to solve it in cylindrical coordinates? It is hard to read what your BC are. But [here](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/maple_2021_and_mma_12_3/insu170.htm#317) is a link to examples solving laplace on polar using Mathematica. Modify anyone to fit your BC's you have as I can't read them well.

Comment: And if you want cylindrical, [here](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/maple_2021_and_mma_12_3/insu172.htm#319) are examples.

Comment: @Nasser, yes sorry it is polar, think I confused since we are considering a cylinder but working with the cross section

Comment: @Nasser are you able to access the article? There the problem is correctly formulated

Comment: @Nasser Those links appear to be broken

Comment: @MelaGo pages were rebuild and links changed due to software change in Latex itself. But you could get to all the examples from the top page [here](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/maple_2021_and_mma_12_3/)

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned that you were able to solve this by hand, using separation of variables, I'll show you how to do the same using Mathematica.

The Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates. I changed `phi` to `u` to avoid conflict with the coordinate name.

```
lap = Laplacian[u[r, phi, z], {r, phi, z}, "Cylindrical"];
```

Separate `u[r,phi,z]` into `R[r] P[phi] Z[z]`. Replacing the head `u` in this manner allows the same rule to apply to both the function and its derivatives.

```
lap /. u -> (R[#1] P[#2] Z[#3] &)
(* (P[phi] Z[z] Derivative[1][R][r] + (R[r] Z[z] (P^′′)[phi])/r)/r + 
     P[phi] Z[z] (R^′′)[r] + P[phi] R[r] (Z^′′)[z] *)
```

Divide through by `R[r] P[phi] Z[z]` and simplify.

```
%/(R[r] P[phi] Z[z]) // Simplify
(* (P^′′)[phi]/(r^2 P[phi]) + (Derivative[1][R][r]/r + 
    (R^′′)[r])/R[r] + (Z^′′)[z]/Z[z] *)
```

I now have three terms which are "separated". Apply the condition that terms like R''/R, P''/P, Z''/Z must each be constants since r,phi,z can be independently varied. Start by converting the sum to a list.

```
List @@ %
(* {(P^′′)[phi]/(r^2 P[phi]), (Derivative[1][R][r]/r + (R^′′)[r])/
     R[r], (Z^′′)[z]/Z[z]} *)
```

Now form equations equating each term which depends only on one variable to a constant - here a,b,c. (Reordered since the usual convention is r,phi,z and we have phi,r,z).

```
Thread[% == {b, a, c}]
(* {(P^′′)[phi]/(r^2 P[phi]) == b, (
  Derivative[1][R][r]/r + (R^′′)[r])/R[r] == a, (Z^′′)[z]/Z[z] == c} *)
```

Now just cut/paste these terms into `DSolve` with the function, parameters typed in manually and solve.

```
DSolve[(Derivative[1][R][r]/r + (R^′′)[r])/R[r] == a, R, r]
(* {{R -> Function[{r}, BesselJ[0, I Sqrt[a] r] C[1] + 
           BesselY[0, -I Sqrt[a] r] C[2]]}} *)

DSolve[(P^′′)[phi]/(r^2 P[phi]) == b, P, phi]
(* {{P -> Function[{phi}, E^(Sqrt[b] phi r) C[1] + E^(-Sqrt[b] phi r) C[2]]}} *)

DSolve[(Z^′′)[z]/Z[z] == c, Z, z]
(* {{Z -> Function[{z}, E^(Sqrt[c] z) C[1] + E^(-Sqrt[c] z) C[2]]}} *)
```

You can now take these pure functions, form the product for `u`, and impose your boundary conditions. Remember your constants aren't independent - they sum to zero, so replace one with the sum of the other two.

There also appear to be other questions on the site which show how to do this more directly using `DSolve` with Dirichet/Neumann boundary conditions. You might want to check these as well.

Comment: Thank you very much @jdp! I am about to compare your answer with my solution. Just a curiosity: what you proposed is in cylindrical coordinates, if I repeat it in polar ones does it work simply by removing z? I mean, just with the radius r an the angle theta?

Comment: Yes, it should work for any number of variables, and for any coordinate system, since the choice of coordinate system affects the form of the Laplacian, and not the separation, which takes the same form (aside from the number of coordinates).

Comment: ok I am going to try out all of this and update you! Also, this afternoon I have tried to read the various proposals using DSolve with Dirichet/Neumann boundary conditions but I reckon I still have to improve my skills to truly understand them

Comment: Dirichlet/Neumann are useful for complex boundaries since they give more precise control, but DSolve can often handle simpler cases by just specifying the conditions along with the equations. Check the DSolve documentation for that. You might want to attempt a solution and post some code; that's likely to attract more attention and get additional answers to your question.